# How to open web based PDF with pdf2txt in Python3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pdf

I'm successfuly parsing local PDFs with pdfminer pdf2txt in Python3.
I use the following code:

```
Python3 pdf2txt.py -A -M 15.0 -L 0.3 -W 0.2 -F 0.5 -V -o output.txt -t text input.pdf
```

I was wondering if there is any way I can use pdf web link instead of local file. I'm not sure how I can declare this. I tried with quotes and parentheses but there is error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately `pdf2txt.py` doesn't support the parsing of streamed PDF documents. The internals require seeking within the file, which is difficult to achieve with a stream.

Your only option is to download the PDF document to your file system and then call `pdf2txt.py` on it. There a lots of tools to download URL resources, e.g. curl, wget, et al., or you could write your own with Python.

You could easily make a shell, batch, or Python script to download the PDF file to a temporary file, run `pdf2txt.py`, and then clean up.

Comment: <code>import wget
file_url = 'http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/documents/2995521/7247552/3-04052016-BP-EN.pdf/fd9d9755-e9d0-4389-a0e8-8fa879efa375'
file_name = wget.download(file_url)<code> This one is working just fine. I was wondering if there is any way I can define the name of the output file. So far it takes the original name witch make it more complicated for processing.

Comment: Usage

    python -m wget [options] <URL>

    options:
        -o --output FILE|DIR output filename or directory

It this one.

Comment: @AlIvon: re your first comment, `file_name = wget.download(file_url, output_filename)` will write the file to the name given in `output_filename`.

Answer (score 0):

Python has `urllib` in the standard library, for retrieving the contents of a URL you can use [`urlretrieve`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve):

```
import urllib2
urllib.urlretrieve('http://www.example.com/myfile.pdf', 'myfile_local.pdf')
```

In Python 3 I believe this is tucked away slightly deeper, in `urllib.request.urlretrieve`

I don't know what OS you're using but you also might want to just use something like the `wget` program from the command line, that way you don't have to write any Python code to do the retrieval.